# Why did Bundle Update alter CSS?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, bundle-install

I ran bundle update and now my background color `$body-bg: #2c3e50;` is now white and a few little css things have been altered.

Do you know why this is and what I can do to fix it?

I'm open to redoing bundle install if there is a way to do that - not ideal though.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',                '4.2.0.rc3'
gem 'sass-rails',           '5.0.0.beta1'
gem 'uglifier',             '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',         '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',         '4.0.0.beta2'
gem 'turbolinks',           '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',             '2.2.3'
gem 'bcrypt',               '3.1.7'
gem 'will_paginate',        '3.0.7'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem "letter_opener", :group => :development
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'cocoon'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'
gem 'haml'
gem 'sdoc',                 '0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'omniauth-facebook'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'    #Needed for Heroku
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'     #Needed for Heroku
end
```

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say your bootstrap gem was updated.

Comment: All looks the same as an older version @patrick. Do you know how I can fix it though? It doesnt make sense even in a new version why `$body-bg: #2c3e50` would stop reading and become white no matter what color I set now.

Comment: Have you restarted your server?

Comment: First I'd check that its not some weird caching browser thing. Try an incognito and check that. Then I'd use developer tools to see which file was setting it as white. Then I'd check that the colour you want is not being overridden by a file included after that.

Comment: Great - you add your own answer too for anyone else who comes across the same issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It wasn't bundle update that was the problem. When I ran a scaffold it created scaffolds.css.scss that overrode my css. Deleted that and I'm good.